# How to prove $\sum\frac{1}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\ge 2\left(\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ab}}-1\right)$ for $ab+bc+ca=1.$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge0: ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove $$\frac{1}{a+\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{1}{b+\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{1}{c+\sqrt{ab}}\ge 2\left(\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ab}}-1\right)$$
I thought we can use C-S
$$\frac{1}{a+\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{1}{b+\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{1}{c+\sqrt{ab}}\ge \frac{9}{a+b+c+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{ba}}$$

But how to get $$\frac{9}{a+b+c+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{ba}}\ge 2\left(\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ab}}-1\right) ?$$
Thank you for the help.

> **Updated editing** Does it exist mimimal value of $$\frac{1}{a+\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{1}{b+\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{1}{c+\sqrt{ab}}?$$
> What do we get after expanding all ?

By computer $$\frac{1}{a+\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{1}{b+\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{1}{c+\sqrt{ab}}\ge 2.59776$$

Comment: How did you get the result $2.59776$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof.**

I'll give a proof using isolated fudging idea.
Indeed, we will prove$$\frac{1}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\ge \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{bc}}-\frac{2a}{a+b+c}. \tag{*}$$
(Taking cyclic sum on $(*)$ and the desired result follows.)

Can you go futher ?

---

Comment: What is the next ?

Comment: Now I see it is trivial by squaring both side

Comment: Dear @Dragonboy, I don't like spam. I think every word we say must be included with our action, that makes our words becomes more believable.

Comment: No! What did you think ? I don't want to write it since it is very complicated

Comment: Ok, it is not a big deal. I wrote the answer in hurry. I'll add more detail later.

Comment: Sure, take your time. I will accept it.

Comment: @TATAbox Nice isolated fudging.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you. It is inspired by your previous solutions.

Comment: @RiverLi Are you Xuezhi Yang ?

Comment: @TATAbox Clearly no.

Answer (score 0):

*A full proof of TATA box's idea.*

Proof of $(*).$

Notice that $(*)$ is obviously true when $a=0$ and $\dfrac{2a}{1+\sqrt{bc}}\le 2a.$

Multiplying $(*)$ by $a+b+c,$ it suffices to prove$$\frac{a+b+c}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\ge \frac{2(b+c)}{1+\sqrt{bc}}, $$or$$(a+b+c)\left(1+\sqrt{bc}\right)\ge 2(b+c)\left(a+\sqrt{bc}\right).$$By using CBS \begin{align*}
    (a+b+c)\left(1+\sqrt{bc}\right)&=\sqrt{[(b+c-a)^2+4a(b+c)][bc+a(b+c)]}+(a+b+c)\sqrt{bc}\\&\ge \sqrt{bc}(b+c-a)+2a(b+c)+(a+b+c)\sqrt{bc}\\&=2(b+c)\left(a+\sqrt{bc}\right).
\end{align*}
Hence, $(*)$ is proven. The proof is done. Equality holds at $a=b=1;c=0$ and cyclic permutations.

Comment: Nice solution! It's from Michael Rozenberg.